# form button behaving weirdly in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm making a form which accepts some details & can only be accessed when you are logged in.

Here is a video to the problem i have faced. Please help me where i am going wrong. The form works perfectly for mobile view but not for normal web view. I think so there is something wrong with the my state management.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YAEPXTe8dZdR0xcKFhSDPqDLIkLDVQTt/view?usp=share_link

```
<form className='login-form addAdmin'>
                <h1>Add Health Partner</h1>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Full Name" 
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                <input 
                    type="email" 
                    placeholder="Email" 
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Mobile number" 
                    onChange={e => setNumber(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    placeholder="Password" 
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                    />
                  
                  <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Address" 
                    onChange={e => setAddress(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Specialization" 
                    onChange={e => setSpecialization(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Experience" 
                    onChange={e => setExperience(e.target.value)} 
                    required
                />
                
                <button type='submit' onClick={e=>handleSubmit(e)}>
                    Add
                </button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a console.log inside `handleSubmit` to see if it's being called when you click the button on the normal view?

Comment: Also, I would move `handleSubmit` from the button to your `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` so that you can submit the form by pressing the Enter key.

Comment: I did try console.log at onClick on the button, it didn't get triggered. I just directly got logged out

Comment: That is very strange. I don't see anything obvious from your code snippet that would prevent the `onClick` from firing.

Comment: Try changing `<button type="submit" />` to `<button type="button" />`